# how to correct an incorrectly imported project in Intellij. Getting error - Not a valid project ID

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I cloned my repo and using the existing `build.sbt`, I imported the project in `Intellij` (I don't remember the setting I used when doing so). I notice that `Intellij` have the project a name of its own - `web_3075` while the name of my project is `TestProject` (`name := "TestProject"`). Now when I try to compile the project, I get the error `Not a valid project ID: web_3075`. How could I solve the issue?

Could I safely delete `.idea` file and import the project again?

Comment: Yes, delete `.idea` directory and reimport from `build.sbt`.

Comment: thanks. Could you also please tell me what import setting should I use so that Intellij gives the correct project name?

Comment: Default settings should work. If not, file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with the sample project to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround (but certainly not preferred approach). Unless I made some mistake, `Intellij` should fix this issue

1) I imported the project using `build.sbt`. I let `Intellij` do what it likes
2) It gives my project a name - `web_5012`. It creates .idea directory which has modules directory and some files. The trick is to replace `web_5012` with your project name in all the files in `.idea` (.NAME file, modules.xml, scala_compiler.xml)and to replace `web_5012.iml` and `web_5012-build.iml` in `.idea/modules` with your project's `iml` files